JPA CriteriaBuilder : List top class with inner Class list with constraints
I have a relation between 3 Entities (Invoice and InvoiceRating adn User)
I'm not able to produce a invoice list sorted by rating for a specific user. Even if there is no rating, the invoice should be listed (user is just a parameter to filter rating)
{
  invoiceA :
   rating:2
   others fields
  invoiceB : 
   rating:3
   others fields
  invoiceC :
   others fields
}

@Entity
public class Invoice  {
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<InvoiceRating> ratings;
}
@Entity
public class InvoiceRating {
    @EmbeddedId
    BusinessTransactionRating ratingKey;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("transactionId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    Invoice invoice;

    int rating;
}
@Embeddable
public class BusinessTransactionRating {
    @Column(name = "transaction_id")
    Long transactionId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    Long userId;

}
@Entity
public class User {
}

The code that works :
CriteriaQuery<Invoice> criteriaQuery = cBuilder.createQuery(Invoice.class);
Root<Invoice> rootInvoice = criteriaQuery.from(Invoice.class);

pageable.getSort().stream().forEach(order -> { // sorting
         Path<Object> prop = rootInvoice.get(order.getProperty());
     list.add(order.isAscending() ? cBuilder.asc(prop) : cBuilder.desc(prop));
            // finalQuery.orderBy();
        });
CriteriaQuery<Invoice> criteriaQueryOrder = finalQuery.orderBy(list);
        // TO DO / Add the count Line and the rebuild pageImpl
TypedQuery<Invoice> queryPaginate = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQueryOrder);

What I have to do to add a select of InvoiceRating that are filtered by a User?

It isn't clear exactly what you are after - are you trying to get Invoice instances back and manipulate what is in their ratings collection? If you want filtered, sorted InvoiceRating instances, query for them directly "select ir from InvoiceRating ir where ir.user. = :someUserValue". Or are you looking to filter Invoices on invoice.ratings.user. ?

Weel, I want to retrieve all invoice with the ordering of rating of a specific user. In sql i have something like that : select * from   (
SELECT DISTINCT
i1_0.id,
r1_0.rating
FROM
sales_invoice i1_0
    LEFT JOIN
sales_invoice_rating r1_0 ON i1_0.id = r1_0.invoice_id
    AND i1_0.id = r1_0.invoice_id
    AND r1_0.user_id = 1

WHERE
i1_0.account = 1
ORDER BY r1_0.rating desc
)  sales_invoice ;

In theory, all you are missing is a join on rootInvoice.join("ratings", JoinType.LEFT), where you then use the rating in your filter with cBuilder.equals(rating.get("user").get("userId"), yourUserId) and in the ordering finalQuery.orderBy(cBuilder.desc(rating.get("rating")))

Thx @Chris, I get the same conclusion ... but , the strange things, is the sql generated add 2 join when I add the join("rating", JoinType.left).  SELECT DISTINCT
i1_0.id,
r1_0.rating,
i1_0.user
FROM
sales_invoice i1_0
JOIN
sales_invoice_rating r2_0 ON i1_0.id = r2_0.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN
sales_invoice_rating r1_0 ON i1_0.id = r1_0.invoice_id
AND i1_0.id = r2_0.invoice_id
AND r2_0.user_id = 1
WHERE
i1_0.account = 1
ORDER BY r1_0.rating DESC . (by the way rating is also a pb , i need only the invoice)

Show the full query being build (dynamic filters are a pain to figure out exactly what is being used), but I suspect you'll find your code is calling  join("rating", JoinType.left) more than once: You will want to call it only once and reuse that existing join in the order clause. It is also using the user id in the join on clause - did you do that on the join clause directly? If so, make sure you use the result of that operation in the order clause.

@Chris, yes there is two Join (one without Left) and 2nd with Left (I want this one) generated, the first join is generated due to the entity relation (i just discover it), and I don't know to avoid that. I think that I have to change the relations inside the models to prevent the first Join (I just discover that feature) ....

You have it mapped as lazy, so I dont think the join is from the model. Show the full criteria query api being called (in a unit test would be better), but I still believe it is a query call you are making: r2 has the user_id filter logic while r1 is used in the order by, both of which I believe you are doing in your query.

@Chris, thank for your support, finally after stop to dig you just gave me the last required information. Your analyse was correct, I used the wrong key (from the root instead from the join) . I also discover how to use the "select" with the join and the root .... whooaaa impressive results.  What I can do for you (I'm new in stackoverflow, I see on your profile some rewards, how to participate ?)

Post an answer to share it with others it might help!

After digging and the @Chris helps, I have the solution.
To realize a Join LEFT (and only a join Left) it's important to use the property of the join in the request and not the property of the root class.
Join<Invoice, InvoiceRating> join = root.join(Invoice.Fields.ratings, JoinType.LEFT);

        Predicate invoiceSelection = cb.equal(root.get(BusinessTransaction.Fields.id),
                join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields.ratingKey)
                        .get(BusinessTransactionRating.Fields.transactionId));

        Predicate userSelection = (cb.equal(join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields.user), user));
        join.on(userSelection, invoiceSelection);

join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields.user) -> instead of ...
root.get(BusinessTransaction.Fields.id),
                join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields_user).

In the case where the get is realized from the root, a Join is also realized and the result is different. You will have request with 2 joins -> Join .... Join LEFT and it's not what you want.
Then you can do :
cq.where(query).distinct(true).orderBy((orderBylist))
.select(cb.array(join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields.rating), rootInvoice));

Note: For the ordering, you also have to specify the rating from the join
Path<Object> prop = join.get(InvoiceRating.Fields.rating);
orderBylist.add(order.isAscending() ? cb.asc(prop) : cb.desc(prop));

